# Water depth on OpenStreetMaps

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

Is it possible to render the water depth on OSM? I imagine something like the satellite view from Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible.

The representation will look like [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Water_Depth#Data_for_water_depths). Note that a `Point` has an attribute called `Depth`.

Here are a couple of references from OSM wiki

1. [Water Depth](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Water_Depth)
2. [Open Sea map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap) (is part of and uses the same database as OpenStreetMap)

Comment: OK, but would you think about a example. From the second link you've posted: "We are still searching for a way to display water depth and a method of displaying the profile of the sea bed. We are also experimenting with AIS (german)."

Comment: A lot of the depth stuff is still [in development](https://wiki.52north.org/bin/view/Geostatistics/OpenSeaMapDepthMap). Here is a [demo](http://dev.openseamap.org/water_depth/water_depth.php).